# How can we insert images as a data in sqlite database while working on android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

in an application where we want to display images directly from the database can inserting records which contains images valid??

I tried searching on google for some existing references but did not find the tutorial needed.

Comment: Android's SQLite API is not well-suited for large blobs of binary data like images. I recommend that you store the images as files and store filenames in the database.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay thanks for the help.